# What if a thin translucent veil was drawn over the sun?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, alternate-reality

Imagine that the Earth is completely unharmed and not threatened by any weapon or disaster and is still spinning on its axis.

However, a thin **translucent** veil slowly starts spreading over the sun and within a day or two, completely envelopes the sun to the extent that no heat can get out of the Sun but only a bare amount of light (such as we see on very cloudy days) gets through. Let us assume that the heat from the Sun is somehow dissipated elsewhere but does not reach the earth. Only a dim light reaches the earth.

What would the sky on the Earth look like in that scenario?

and

What would happen to the climate of the Earth and the average temperature of the atmosphere in :

1. A week's time
2. A month's time
3. A year's time
4. In a decade
5. In a century

Comment: I am not sure I understand your description. Can you be more precise with what you consider heat and what you consider light? Also, please note that science based cannot be the only tag in a question

Comment: What L.Dutch said plus please narrow this down to a particular area of effect, climate for example, otherwise a decent answer is going to fill a small library.

Comment: @Ash not sure it will. If the veil is thin, but still absorb all heat, we can expect some damage. Even more if it's in solar flare range.

Comment: @Kepotx The core question about the sky is simple but the "what would happen in...?" piece is a huge amount of information if it's about the whole world effect rather than being narrowed down to "what would happen to X in...?"

Comment: What do you mean by *"no heat can get out of the Sun but only a bare amount of light"*? What do you believe to be the difference between heat and light? You do understand that the Sun is radiates light simply because it is hot? The "thin veil" will very quickly become as hot as the Sun and emit the exact same light. Which is to say, just forget about the thin veil. The intensity of the Sun's energy output drops by a factor of 100; that's all the question needs to say; never mind the mechanism.

Comment: The basic premise of your query is very interesting, but there is a problem.  Which question do you want us to answer?  Your title question focuses on the Sun --- a veil has surrounded her.  The question in the body focuses on the Earth --- the appearance of the sky.  Lack of focus may get your question closed. Please check out the [help] and [tour] so you can get a better idea how to word your queries here!

Comment: @L.Dutch - How much more detailed can I get? Anyway, I added more details to make this less broad so hopefully it will fit the specificity required.

Comment: @Ash - I added more details so the answer should fit on a small page rather than a library.

Comment: @Kepotx - Thank you, I knew that we can expect damage on Earth so I wanted to see how much damage we could expect....apocalypse or survival of the fittest or something else...?

Comment: @AlexP - Let us assume that the veil drawn over the sun is thin but indestructible and can withstand the heat of a thousand suns (Or a few stars as big as Betelgeuse) without burning up or being damaged. The mechanism by which this happens is unknown so it is of no consequence. Let us assume that it is as it is and see wht happens.

Comment: @elemtilas - I specifically asked about the **earth** in my question. I just mentioned what happened to the sun to set up the premise. My question is **not** about the sun. Pleas read the question carefully before stating that the question lacks focus.

Comment: That may be your intention, but the effect is rather different which is why I took the time to explain.  If you'd care to edit your question, i.e., remove the issues making it too broad, then I'd happily vote to reopen!  Keep in mind: SE operates on the model of *one focused query gets one focused answer*.

Answer (score 3):

I assume OP means that Earth received no infrared radiation from sun ("no heat"), and a small amount of light. I am pretty sure it is possible; even now we have window glass that lets some light in, but blocks out most of the the heat.

Under these parameters, the earth's sky will immediately look like dusk or nighttime (depending on how little visible light we get from the sun). Moon will go dim as well (it reflects light from the sun)

After a bit of time, Earth's surface will start cooling down, so **ever-colder winter** everywhere. Eventually all water vapor will fall down as rain or snow, and freeze on the ground, so **no more clouds**. I am not sure how long it will take, but I know normal winter weather takes like a month or two to set in, so I'd give it a few months till no clouds.

After even more time, earth might cool down to the point that **oxygen and nitrogen in atmosphere will turn into liquid** or freeze. This would cause very clear skies with ton of bright stars (also need a spacesuit to survive on the surface). This will likely take at least a year. And maybe will not happen at all, since earth's core and magma will remain hot. Somebody with better knowledge needs to answer that.

PS As others pointed out in the comments, covering entire Sun with a veil creates a major problem of what to do with the enormous amount of heat that sun generates. A more feasible alternative is to have a ring that shades only the orbital plane, and simply reflects heat into space.

Or a circle shading only Earth (kinda like moon during an solar eclipse). The circle will need propulsion to stay in the right position, and that could come from tilting the circle to act as a solar sail.

### Alternative approach

As AlexP said, a possible re-interpretation version of this Q would be: "what will happen to Earth if it orbits further away from the sun?"

I know Jupiter  is 5 times further out, so it gets 25 times less light and heat from the sun, and it is way below water freezing temperature, but oxygen and nitrogen will still be a gas. 
https://www.huffpost.com/entry/what-the-sun-looks-like-from-other-planets_n_577ec142e4b0344d514e9182

Uranus is 20 times further, so 400 times less energy, and it has surface temperature low enough for most atmospheric gasses to freeze: https://space-facts.com/uranus/

Comment: Instead of exploring all possible OP's intention, wouldn't be better to ask a clarifying comment and wait for the OP to react to it?